# run npm script from different repository

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to launch an npm `run` script located in repository **A** from repository **B** (both cloned locally).

In repository **A** the script is defined like this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "my-script": "node my-script.js"
}
```

... and it's launched with `npm run my-script`. It works fine when launched this way with no errors. The script compiles some files and copies them to different folders inside repo **A**.

So, my first thought to be able to run that process from repository **B** was to simply call `node my-script.js` from npm.

```
"scripts": {
  "my-script-in-other-repo": "node ../path/to/repo/my-script.js"
}
```

... and call it with `npm run my-script-in-other-repo` in repository **B**.

Unfortunately this approach throws a bunch of Node and NPM errors which do nothing to help solve this. Stuff like `Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.`. [Here is the output](https://gist.github.com/PierBover/f71ac1a471f3c48fd320b4f6e13cf2c6).

My intuition tells me it may be a problem with the Node context, or maybe Node in repository **B** can't access the dev packages in repository **A**.

A quick and dirty solution could be to replicate `my-script.js` in repository **B** changing the paths of the files and copying the same dependencies... but it is kinda ugly.

Is there a cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: 1. You might've looked at the useless part of the error message. Can you show us the output verbatim? 2. Are you in control of **B**? If you are, you can make "my-script.js" a "binary" and run it as a dev dependency. 3. slight nitpick: npm is not an acronym, just keep it in lower case. ;)

Comment: Hey @E_net4 I've edited my question. Yes I'm in control of both repos.

Comment: The actual error lies before npm's error message, and is caused by  `npm run bundle-css && npm run build-js && npm run build-js-dependencies && npm run sync-repos && npm run bundle-css-XXXXXXXXXXXXX`. You may wish to look into that.

Comment: You are right. I've scrolled up and Node complaints about a null variable when running from repository B. But when running  from repository A the script works fine...

Comment: A null variable, you say? Or is it a missing module? Can you show a snippet?

Comment: `/Volumes/Data/Projects/Github/XXXXXX/bundle-css.js:18
 fs.writeFile(sassResult, result.css, function () {
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null
    at Object.callback (/Volumes/Data/Projects/Github/XXXXX/bundle-css.js:18:33)
    at options.error (/Volumes/Data/Projects/Github/XXXX/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:274:32)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have your project **A** as a dependency of **B**, and that you have scripts in **A** that are intended to be executed directly as independent applications.Luckily, there is a painless way in npm to register such scripts and run them from dependents.

In project **A**, use the ["bin" property in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) to keep your executable scripts:

```
"bin": {
  "A-script": "my-script.js"
},
```

In project **B**, keep **A** as a dependency (or devDependency, depending on when you need it), then run `A-script` as if it were a command:

```
"scripts": {
  "my-script-in-other-repo": "A-script"
}
```

However note that, although module resolution still works when running scripts from a foreign working directory, resolving other kinds of resources using `fs` depends on the current working directory. According to the [docs regarding fs operations](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> The relative path to a filename can be used. Remember, however, that this path will be relative to `process.cwd()`.

If you need to load a resource file (such as a css file) residing in some place relative to your source code, consider using the [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) global variable in order to resolve to that file. This could have actually been the root of your problem.