# npm run multiple services including serverless offline from different directories

Tags: node.js, package.json, serverless, serverless-offline, concurrently

**Currently**

1. I have a local test environment setup.
2. I am trying to migrate to *serverless* and have setup *serverless-offline* for local testing.

I cannot get my existing client + server to run, alongside *serverless-offline*.

DIRECTORY:

```
root:
- package.json
- /my-project
-- /serverless
--- ...
-- handler.js
-- serverless.yml
```

PACKAGE.JSON *<-- uses concurrently to run multiple services simultaneously*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm start --prefix client\" \"node index.js\" \"serverless offline start\""
  }
```

**Problem**

When running npm start at root directory, the following error is returned:

`Serverless command "offline" not found. Did you mean "config"? Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands.`

Note: when I run `serverless offline start` in `\my-project`, the command executes successfully and *serverless-offline* runs.

**Question**

1. Is there a way to run the `serverless offline start` command in the context of `/my-project` or
2. Do I need to reorganise my directory structure?

**Notes**

I have tried answer [run npm script from different repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309807/run-npm-script-from-different-repository) but failed to get it working. Perhaps because I am trying to run a command (i.e. serverless) not a script file from a different directory context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with serverless, but rather my novice experience with setting up scripts within package.json. There were 2 options to run `serverless offline start` from the parent project folder.

**Option 1**

Inserting `cd my-project &&` before invoking `serverless offline start`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm start --prefix client\" \"node index.js\" \"cd my-project && serverless offline start\""
  }
```

**Option 2**

Adding `--prefix my-project` to `serverless offline start` command. *Note: I have not tested option 2*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm start --prefix client\" \"node index.js\" \"serverless offline start --prefix my-project\""
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In serverless, to add serverless "child" projects you must indicate in the main serverless file the functions that belongs to the other packages.

For example, if you have the structure.

```fs
root:
----serverless.yml
----handler.js
----package.json
----index.functions.yml
----src/
-------/serverless.yml
-------/package.json
-------/handler.js
-------/index.functions.yml
-------/handler.js
```

Then, you must to have like this in your main serverless.yml file:

```yaml
    service: main-serverless
    plugins:
      - serverless-offline
    functions:
      - ${file(./index.functions.yml)}
      - ${file(./src/index.functions.yml)}
```

if you want to manipulate inside packages you must try using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), with it you can handle nested packages from root dir.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Fernando, are you suggesting that there is no way to invoke the serverless command from the `my-project` context? Because I am not trying to add a child serverless project. There is no `serverless.yml` at root level.

Comment: If you invoke `serverless offline start` outside  `my-project` folder it won't work beacause serverless waits for a `serverless.yml` in your current directory to use it as a reference for the project. So i think it is no possible way to do it in the root project. I think you can't indicate the file manually neither.

Comment: Perhaps. I managed to get `serverless offline start` to run alongside my existing client + server. I have also done some research to confirm your suggestion that reorganisation the structure to put serverless.yml at top level of project structure might be best. Whether the previous structure would have prevented it from work, I cannot confirm. Thank you for your help.